# setting a picture as app background and using it for opening other screens

Tags: android, image, background, hyperlink

I am trying to set a background picture to my app and using this picture similar to Java script as a map for links. Setting the picture itself was not the problem. This is done in the XML but defining the links and event handlers I have no idea how to implement that. Is there anything out there that I can use?

Comment: Problem here is that you cannot easily show user touch events if you are using only picture which has there links to other screens.

Answer (score 1):

i m not sure but this may help u, use broadcast receiver or any service to listen the background image of your app and save that image link or resource location in file , when application load that image will set to app background (you need to save image url or image location for retrieving)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am not sure it will help. I never did what you describe before so I need to have a look at the commands before I can say something. Anyway it sounds pretty complicated. I hoped for an easier solution. Thanks anyway.